# How do I get a number to render in my UI with a space after every 4 characters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angular-filters

I have a 16 digit property that comes back for example(1234123412341234). I would like it to render on my UI with a space every 4 number characters for example(1234 1234 1234 1234). I'm using Angular JS so I'm looking for a way to accomplish this. I'm pretty sure it's either a custom Angular filter or regex related, but my knowledge of either and how to implement it is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS filter is easy to setup. Just accept one parameter and apply any JS formatting on it. Here is a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\d{4}(?=.)/g, '$& '); // your format filter here
  };
});
app.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = 1234123412341234;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    {{test | myFilter}}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(I took regex code from [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205745/8495123)'s answer. Feel free to use any other regex)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex with lookahead.

The [Positive Lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) looks for the pattern after the equal sign, but does not include it in the match.

> **x(?=y)**
>
> Matches 'x' only if 'x' is followed by 'y'. This is called a lookahead.
>
> For example, `/Jack(?=Sprat)/` matches 'Jack' only if it is followed by 'Sprat'. `/Jack(?=Sprat|Frost)/` matches 'Jack' only if it is followed by 'Sprat' or 'Frost'. However, neither 'Sprat' nor 'Frost' is part of the match results.

```js
function format(s) {
    return s.toString().replace(/\d{4}(?=.)/g, '$& ');
}

console.log(format(1234123412341234));
```

Comment: I'm now thinking I probably need to use an angular filter. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match()` and then `join()` with a whitespace.

```js
var str = '1234123412341234';
var res = str.match(/.{1,4}/g).join(' ');
console.log(res);
```